# New Crash Logs do not Appear in Organizer for one specific iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, crash

Does anyone know why the organizer will not find my new crash reports for one iOS device but it does for my other devices?

Let me explain: I was demoing an app today on both my iPad 3 and iPhone 5. The app is still in beta so I experienced crashes on both devices. When I returned home later that day, the new crashes from the iPhone 5 appeared right away in the Organizer window. However, the iPad 3 did not have its new crash logs appear. The only logs that came up (even after waiting several minutes and restarting the device) were from a month ago. I am running iOS 6.01 on the iPad 3 and iOS 6.1 beta 3 on the iPhone 5. Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the console for the device to see if there is any extra information about why this might be happening.   I've seen this occur when the device is full of crash reports,  if this is the case you will get info about this in the console for the device.